# UWP device total memory

Tags: c#, memory, size, win-universal-app

How do you determine a devices total memory? I would like to use a sequential program flow on low memory devices and a more asynchronous flow on higher memory devices.

Example: On a device with 1GB of memory my program works but on  512MB device my program hits an OutOfMemoryException as it is caching images from multiple sites asynchronously.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The MemoryManager class has some static properties to get the current usage and limit for the application.

```
// Gets the app's current memory usage.
MemoryManager.AppMemoryUsage

// Gets the app's memory usage level.
MemoryManager.AppMemoryUsageLevel

// Gets the app's memory usage limit.
MemoryManager.AppMemoryUsageLimit
```

You can react to the limit changing using the `MemoryManager.AppMemoryUsageLimitChanging` event

```
private void OnAppMemoryUsageLimitChanging(
    object sender, AppMemoryUsageLimitChangingEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("AppMemoryUsageLimitChanging: old={0} MB, new={1} MB", 
        (double)e.OldLimit / 1024 / 1024,
        (double)e.NewLimit / 1024 / 1024));
}
```

You can use the application's memory limit to decide how best to manage your memory allocation.

Comment: How to get the total RAM installed in the device?

Comment: On 64-bit windows 11 with 16GB of RAM AppMemoryUsageLimit returns 28GB. Not so useful as a substitute for installed physical memory function.